# how to add a custom product tab like details tab on product page in magento 2.1

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.1, product-tag

I have created attributes like features and specification for product. Can anyone guide me how to show these attributes below details tab on product page.
I'm using magento 2.1 with molly theme.Please refer the image.
[image: below the details tab.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2 to apply the new tab in product detail page is very easy task. Use below steps and check it out. It will display the tab in your theme.

1. Create file `catalog_product_view.xml` in the app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/layout

In the file write the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="deliveryinfo.tab" as="deliveryinfo" template="product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Question</argument>
        </arguments>
        </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. create the file `delivery_info.phtml` in the path app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.

In the file you can write any content or you can call the static block like this

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('delivery_info')->toHtml(); ?>
```

3. `delivery_info` block we have to create in admin side `Content/Block`.

Now check in the Detail page.

Answer (score 0):

The above steps work for blocks, if you want to add product attributes in product view page add following code to `delivery_info.phtml` :

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getattribute_ID(), 'attribute_ID') ?>
```